# SQL Server 2000 Memory Status

Tags: memory, sql-server

I'm trying to get a better idea of how my SQL 2000 instance is using it's memory. I've run DBCC MEMORYSTATUS and I'm hoping someone can give me a better idea of how to interpret the output.

My main concern is the 'Other' section of the buffer distribution. It is currently using by far the most pages at 166,000. Considering that SQL has only about 2GB of availible RAM, the fact that most of that is being used by 'Other' worries me.

Below is the full output . I appreciate any help you can offer.

```
Buffer Distribution Buffers  
Stolen      30595
Free        966
Procedures  208
Inram       0
Dirty       8424
Kept        0
I/O         137
Latched     437
Other       166065
```

Answer (score 0):

Check http://support.microsoft.com/kb/271624/en-us for details about DBCC MEMORYSTATUS fields.

There are a lot of performance counters for SQL Server [memory] in system Performance monitor.
Try to use it - it can be more specific and useful.
Using Performance monitor you can collect historical data and analyse it instead of checking momentary memory state with DBCC MEMORYSTATUS

Comment: Perfmon is actually what lead me to use the DBCC Memorystatus. I found that the counters in perfmon weren't very specific. I was hoping the DBCC would give me more info, and I think it did as the 'other' buffer seems to be my issue. I've also already been to that link, Microsoft doesn't give much info on what 'Other' is.